# Java Thread Random

Tags: java, multithreading, random, printing, sleep

Ok, so I want to generate a random number for printing in a thread. One and two work fine, but three just prints out the same random number. So if a generates 1928, it sleeps for 1928 over and over again. How do I make dynamically random numbers? Three is the only one where I want to interrupt if another random number(num) is smaller than 1000.

```
package thread;

import java.util.Random;

public class Threads {

public static Thread one;
public static Thread two;
public static Thread three;

public static int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
public static String letters[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
public static float negatives[] = { -1, -2, -3, -4, -5 };
public static Random rand = new Random();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    startSequences();
    one.setName("one");
    two.setName("two");
    three.setName("three");
    one.start();
    two.start();
    three.start();
}

public static void startSequences() {
    one = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out
                        .println("Numbers\n-----------------------------------");
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    int a = rand.nextInt(3999);
                    System.out.printf(
                            "%s is sleeping for %d milliseconds. \n",
                            Thread.currentThread().getName(), a);
                    Thread.sleep(a);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " is done sleeping.");
                    System.out.printf("current number is %s\n", numbers[i]);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.printf("%s has been interrupted. How rude!",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } finally {
                System.out.printf("%s is finally done!\n", Thread
                        .currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    };

    two = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                one.join();
                System.out
                        .println("\nLetters\n-----------------------------------");
                for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                    int a = rand.nextInt(3999);
                    System.out.printf(
                            "%s is sleeping for %d milliseconds.\n", Thread
                                    .currentThread().getName(), a);
                    Thread.sleep(a);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " is done sleeping.");
                    System.out.printf("current letter is %s\n", letters[i]);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.printf("%s has been interrupted. How rude!",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } finally {
                System.out.printf("%s is now done. Finally!", Thread
                        .currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    };

    three = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int num = rand.nextInt(3999);
                two.join();
                if (num < 1000) {
                    System.out
                            .printf("\n%s is being interrupted because the random was %d and lower than 1000.",
                                    Thread.currentThread().getName(), num);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } else {
                    int a = rand.nextInt(3999);
                    System.out
                            .println("\nNegatives-----------------------------------\n");
                    System.out
                            .printf("the number was %s, Therefore, it will not be interrupted.",
                                    num);
                    for (int i = 0; i < negatives.length; i++) {
                        System.out.printf(
                                "\n%s is sleeping for %d milliseconds.",
                                Thread.currentThread().getName(), a);
                        Thread.sleep(a);
                        System.out.printf("\n%s has finished sleeping.",
                                Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.printf(
                                "\ncurrent negative number is %s",
                                negatives[i]);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.printf("\n%s has been interrupted. How rude!",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } finally {
                System.out.printf("\n%s is now done. Finally!", Thread
                        .currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    };
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then for `Thread three` you need to move the random number generation into the loop. Something like,

```
// int a = rand.nextInt(3999);
System.out.println("\nNegatives-----------------------------------");
System.out.printf("the number was %s and will not be interrupted.%n", num);
for (int i = 0; i < negatives.length; i++) {
    int a = rand.nextInt(3999);
```

Answer (score -1):

Without testing, I just checked Random's javadoc. There I find:

> Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.

So you might check the ThreadLocalRandom, if it solves your problem.